# Keep formula unchanged when row is deleted

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to keep the count of how many cells are not empty on a worksheet. We often need to delete rows, but when we do the formula range changes. I always need it to be the cells you see in the formula.

```
=COUNTA($A$2:$A$132)
```

Is there a way to adjust this so that the cell references never change when a row is deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,132))
```